# javascript variables with names starting with a $ are sometimes producing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, naming-conventions

Until very recently,  I've used javascript variable names that start with **$** to indicate that the variables contains jQuery values, i.e.: `$buttons = $( 'button' );`  However, two nights ago, I started getting this error when I tried this when I loaded the page into the latest version of Chrome:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: buttons
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Stack Trace
in src/AppBundle/Controller/pages/myVideos.php at line 6086  -

6086.                               function button_Click( This ) { 
6087.                                 var $buttons = $( 'button' ); 
6088.                               } // End of button_Click( This ) function.
```

However, if I remove the **$** from the buttons variable declaration/assignment, this error doesn't occur.

What seems strange to me about this that whether I have the **$** before buttons or not, in the same page I have lots of other variable declarations in other functions that use the leading **$**, but they don't produce these errors, here is one example:

```
function ytPictureSelect_Click() {
  const ELEMENT_PATH_URI     = 'tr:first>td.webvideourlURI>span';
  const ELEMENT_PATH_PICTURE = 'tr:eq(1)>td.webvideourlPicture';

  var   This                 = ( ( this.tagName === 'TD' )
                                 ? this
                                 : event.target );
  var   $This                = $( This );
  var   $element             = $This.closest( 'table' );
  var   $table               = $element.parent().closest( 'table' );
  var   $webvideourlURI      = $table.find( ELEMENT_PATH_URI );
  var   youTube              = ( $webvideourlURI.attr( 'youTube' ) === 'true' );
  var   embedded             = ( $webvideourlURI.attr( 'embed' ) === 'true' );
  var   ytId                 = $webvideourlURI.attr( 'ytId' );
  var   $webvideourlPictures = $table.find( ELEMENT_PATH_PICTURE )
                               .children( 'textarea, span' );
  :

} // End of ytPictureSelect_Click() function.
```

Anyone know why the buttonClick function doesn't *like* the leading **$**, but all of the other functions using this naming convention, are good?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Symfony ver 2.8 and PHP to create my page, where the page is put into an array and then the array's content is sent to the browser as follows, less the code to actually send the page:

```
$strMAINs[] = <<<"MAIN"
    <script>
      function button_Click( This ) { 
        var $buttons = $( 'button' ); 
      } // End of button_Click( This )
    </script>
MAIN;
```

The above code is the source of the error I'm talking about, there is another, similar statement that creates the other function that works, even though it has $ prefixed variables.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: That's a php error. Seems you have mixed the languages up and are using a javscript function within the php somehow

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your replies.  I put an update in my question that shows my code.

Comment: Charlietfl, I start with a leading $ named variable, if this was a PHP error, then wouldn't the present of a $ be a valid variable, and removing it make the variable invalid?  The problem is actually the other way around.

Comment: charlietfl, you are correct!  The issue was that that I was using double quotes, not single quotes in my Here-String, which cause the PHP compiler to consider the variables with leading $ as substitution variables, which I hadn't intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

charlietfl, is right about this being a PHP error.  My 2nd response details what was happening.

To make these kinds of substitutions clearer I use ${php-variable-name}, but this is only a convention, and there isn't a way, as far as I know, to enforce the use of ${...} versus simply $.  Too bad, because it wreaks havoc on my jQuery statements, when I forget to switch from double quotes to single quotes.